# React-Native android device can't see console remote debugging

Tags: android, react-native

I'm working on a React-Native app, I am testing it on a physical android device, the MOTO Z2 Play. I would run an emulator, except I have an AMD processor on my rig and can't run those emulators, unfortunately.

So I'm trying to enable remote debugging on this device while developing, so I can see console.log() statements that I put in the code. The problem is that when I the debugger opens the browser and I go to the console to view the logs I see the following errors:

[image]

What do these errors mean, and how can I get the console to show logs? Or is there another way I can view logs without having to enable remote debugger? Thanks!

Comment: Did you check documentation? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html#connecting-to-the-development-server

Comment: Yeah, I've gone through those steps to setup the device for running the app, it just throws this error when I try to enable remote debugging so I can see logs.